# Android CTS Failed to write log

Tags: android, cts

I've run the Android 4.2 R4 CTS Suite against a 4.2 build off Aurora for MSM, multiple times: the full suite ( `run cts --plan CTS` ) or individual packages ( `run cts -p android.acceleration` ). This is on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit (virtualized with VMWare Fusion v6)

The test suite executes, with passes and sometimes failures, but then fails to write logs or generate report data:

```
cts-tf > run cts -p android.acceleration
04-02 13:42:20 I/TestInvocation: Starting invocation for 'cts' on build '4.2_r4' on device e05e1f79
04-02 13:42:20 I/e05e1f79: Created result dir 2014.04.02_13.42.20
04-02 13:42:33 I/e05e1f79: Collecting device info
04-02 13:42:34 I/e05e1f79: -----------------------------------------
04-02 13:42:34 I/e05e1f79: Test package android.acceleration started
04-02 13:42:34 I/e05e1f79: -----------------------------------------
04-02 13:42:37 I/e05e1f79: android.acceleration.cts.HardwareAccelerationTest#testIsHardwareAccelerated PASS 
04-02 13:42:37 I/e05e1f79: android.acceleration.cts.HardwareAccelerationTest#testNotAttachedView PASS 
04-02 13:42:38 I/e05e1f79: android.acceleration.cts.SoftwareAccelerationTest#testIsHardwareAccelerated PASS 
04-02 13:42:38 I/e05e1f79: android.acceleration.cts.SoftwareAccelerationTest#testNotAttachedView PASS 
04-02 13:42:38 I/e05e1f79: android.acceleration.cts.WindowFlagHardwareAccelerationTest#testIsHardwareAccelerated PASS 
04-02 13:42:39 I/e05e1f79: android.acceleration.cts.WindowFlagHardwareAccelerationTest#testNotAttachedView PASS 
04-02 13:42:41 E/CtsXmlResultReporter: Failed to write log for device_logcat
04-02 13:42:41 E/CtsXmlResultReporter: Failed to write log for host_log
04-02 13:42:41 I/e05e1f79: android.acceleration package complete: Passed 6, Failed 0, Not Executed 0
04-02 13:42:41 I/e05e1f79: Created xml report file at file:///opt/android-cts/cts4.2/android-cts/tools/./../../android-cts/repository/results/2014.04.02_13.42.20/testResult.xml
04-02 13:42:41 E/CtsXmlResultReporter: Failed to generate report data
```

In the CTS `/repository/logs` & `/repository/results` directories, there are no new log or result entries. There's surprisingly little information about `CtsXmlResultReporter`, so I'm turning to good ol' SO. Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This was just a chmod problem. I need to run multiple versions of CTS (4.2, 4.3, 4.4) and I had created the 4.2 directory structure while root.